# I'm unable to receive the push notification in latest android version(>6) in react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I tried all the solutions but I am unable to get push notification using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification) in android version greater than 6(Marshmallo) in any devices whether it is emulator or any real devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer of this question by myself after wasting my alot of time,

In the case of android version 7 or lower than 7 the push notification will work as usual but in case of android version greater than 7 the channel Id must be provided for the push notification in below example

```
PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
        channelId: "your_unique_channel_id", // (required)
        channelName: "your_channel_name", // (required)
        channelDescription: "A channel to categorise your notifications", // (optional) default: undefined.
        soundName: "default", // (optional) See `soundName` parameter of `localNotification` function
        importance: 1, // (optional) default: 4. Int value of the Android notification importance
        vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration patten if true.
    },
     (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
);
```

first set the channel Id at the time of App launch and then at the time of setting the schedule or push notification pass the Id like this

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
                channelId:"your_unique_channel_id",  //same as passed while setting up the at time of creating channel
                autoCancel: true,
                title: "TITLE",
                message: "MESSAGE",
                vibrate: false,
                vibration: 300,
                playSound: true,
                soundName: 'default'
                date: new Date(),
            })
```

after this I'll be able to get push notification in every device for my react native application